# Trying to run Google Cloud Function Locally getting: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-filestore

I am trying to run functions locally for deployed google cloud functions.

When I run the command:

```
`functions-framework --target=set_playlist in my terminal`
```

I get this error: **TypeError: 'module' object is not callable**

I have successfully installed functions framework. Not sure if I am missing a step in running the virtual environment.

My database is located in firestore and my function is querying that db. I have the database set up.

FYI running in Ubuntu Windows System and python

Comment: Can you share more? Your code, your requirements,...